# Why does it take 100ms to wait for a TThread on Mac OS?

Tags: multithreading, macos, macos-sierra, freepascal

I see in my application that every thread I'm running takes around a 100ms to get finished even though there is nothing to do in the thread itself.

See this sample:

```pascal
program threadtest;

uses
  cThreads, SysUtils, Classes;

type
  TSampleThread = class(TThread)
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

var
  Thread: TThread;
  I: Integer;

procedure TSampleThread.Execute;
begin
  // Nothing
end;

begin
  WriteLn(TimeToStr(Now) + ' Start');
  for I := 0 to 99 do
  begin
    Thread := TSampleThread.Create(True);
    // Thread.Start; // We don't need to start the thread.
    Thread.Free; // This call takes around a 100ms
  end;
  WriteLn(TimeToStr(Now) + ' Finished');
end.
```

The output is

```
23:08:17 Start
23:08:28 Finished
```

As you can see the loop takes around 10 seconds to finish. The call to `Free` (respectively the inner call to `WaitFor`) takes over 100ms.

I don't see this problem on Windows. Why is this happening on Mac OS? How can I do it faster?

Comment: You seem to be assuming 1 tick is 1 ms. Is that correct? https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/sysutils/gettickcount64.html

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks for pointing that out. I changed the sample code, so that it doesn't use `GetTickCount` at all.

Comment: How do you know it is `Thread.Free()` taking the time and not `Thread.Create()`?

Comment: Look into the source code of the `WaitFor` method. Probably, you will find something like `While not FFinished do CheckSynchronize(100);` there...

Comment: https://github.com/alrieckert/freepascal/blob/31cd520717f588484d19b660f4a682bd84ea5750/rtl/unix/tthread.inc#L267-L268